# Why I cannot find Scene Time node in Geometry Nodes in Blender?

Tags: time, geometry, nodes, blender, scene

I am working in Blender and trying to follow some You Tube video tutorials. My following certain videos comes to a halt when I am unable to find one particular node that is supposed to be in Geometry Nodes, "Scene Time". I have gotten pretty good at slowing down and pausing the tutorial so I can see what is being clicked and typed, but I am unsuccessful when attempting to locate the elusive "Scene Time" node that is suppose to be in Geometry nodes. If anyone can give me fix as to why I am unable to locate this node and/or guide me towards finding this node, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's under `Input -> Scene Time`. It was changed in Blender 3.1: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.1/Nodes_Physics "It's no longer necessary to add a #frame driver to get the scene's current animation time, the Scene Time node does that instead". You have probably old version of Blender.

Comment: Jan Husak, thanks. It worked. I downloaded the latest Blender version and found the Scene Time node. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This node is added in 3.1 version ... update your blender to 3.1 or higher and you probably will